Не работают команды Node.js. Что делать?
Я пробовал и переустанавливать и разные команды. Не работаю ни npm ни npx, НИЧЕГО. И выдаёт такую ошибку:
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\es6\validate-engines.js:31
    throw err
    ^

TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\fs-minipass\lib\index.js:136:4)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1358:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1416:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1208:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1024:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1233:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:179:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\log-file.js:5:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1358:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1416:10)

Node.js v20.13.1


после какой команды возникает такая ошибка?

после любой с nmp, npx

попробуйте https://stackoverflow.com/a/70029457/4496422

теперь вот такая ошибка

npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! path C:\Users\misha\AppData\Roaming\npm
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\misha\AppData\Roaming\npm'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\misha\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2024-05-16T16_48_03_106Z-debug-0.log

команда npx create-react-app reactfirst

Все уточнения в вопрос добавляйте пожалуйста, кнопка "править",
